# How to have org-publish automatically publish generated images?

Tags: org-mode, org-publish

I use org-publish to publish HTML exports of org-mode files quite often to share documents with my coworkers, however, I generate a lot of diagrams with `plantuml` and `gnuplot`. These diagrams aren't sent to the remote server when I export the file with `C-c C-e P f`.

My configuration looks like:

```
("org-pastebin"
 :base-directory "~/org/"
 :base-extension "org\\|zsh\\|html\\|png"
 :publishing-directory "/ssh:user@server:~/public_html/org/"
 :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
 :with-toc t
 :html-preamble t)
```

If I have an org-mode file that looks like:

```
* Header
Some prose

#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :file my-file.png :results raw
...
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
[[file:my-file.png]]
```

How can I get Emacs to automatically publish the linked file (my-file.png) in this case? Even if I publish the whole project the images are not copied.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to publish projects consisting of multiple file types I add the following to my `.emacs` file:

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist
  '(("myprojectorg"
     :base-directory "~/path/to/myproject/"
     :publishing-directory "/ssh:user@server:~/public_html/myproject/"
     :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
     :auto-preamble t
     )
    ("myprojectother"
     :base-directory "~/path/to/myproject/"
     :base-extension "css\\|pdf\\|sh"
     :publishing-directory "/ssh:user@server:~/public_html/myproject"
     :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
     )
    ("myprojectimages"
     :base-directory "~/path/to/myproject/images"
     :base-extension "png\\|jpg"
     :publishing-directory "/ssh:user@server:~/public_html/myproject/images"
     :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
     )
    ("myprojectweb" :components("myprojectorg" "myprojectother" "myprojectimages"))
   )
)
```

This defines an entry `myprojectweb` which I use when publishing from org-mode using `C-c C-e P x`. This `myprojectweb` consists of:

- the org file(s) as defined in `myprojectorg`,
- image files as defined in `myprojectimages` (which are in a subdirectory), and
- other files (in this case PDFs, CSS files and shell scripts), which are defined in `myprojectother`.

These last two entries are published using `org-publish-attachment` which does nothing but copy the files to the `publishing-directory`.

Comment: Tested this and it works great, thanks!